# MVP pattern where handle Textview?

Tags: java, android, mvp

I'm just starting with MVP and I want to know where should I setText on my `TextView's`? I received object from `Intent` and i have to do something with it but I don't have idea where. Send it to presenter or just in `onCreate` after intent was received?

Comment: You should do that in the view, don't pass views to presenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass object to presenter.
`Presenter`decides to update view or not. 
For example it can call method `view.showText(String text)`
and your activity in this method should call `setText` of your `TextView`

Comment: so is better idea to put intent into Presenter?

Comment: @Khuzy yes, this is a sense of MVP pattern